# failed to Login to a remote website

Tags: authentication, httpwebrequest, form-submit

I spent too much hours to overcome this, till now with no success

From my site which is developed in MVC im trying to send a login request to a remote site, for example, facebook.

From fiddler It seems that the following inputs are required charset_test, lsd, locale,email, pass.

lsd key seems to be the unique token
Here is my code

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer()
private string GetToken()
{
     Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.facebook.com");
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
     request.CookieContainer = cookies;
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

     Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

     string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();

     HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument(); --> HtmlAgilePack object
     document.LoadHtml(htmlText);
     //Need to check xpath doesn't return null object
     HtmlNode node = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@name='lsd']").First();

     return node.Attributes["Value"].Value;
}

private void Login()
{
    string postData = string.Format("charset_test=fixcharset_test&lsd={0} &locale=en_US&email=myemail&pass=mypass", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(GetToken()));

    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/login.php");
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;     
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(postData);
    requestWriter.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 }

 //After login to facebook suppose to 
 public string void AddFriend()
 {
     Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.facebook.com");
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
     request.CookieContainer = cookies;

     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     string status = response.StatusDescription;
     StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
     string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
     responseReader.Close();
     return responseDat
 }
```

Keep in mind, that facebook is just an example, Im aware of its API, Im trying to login to site with no API.
sadly, the response return a facebook page with a sorry message for unrecognizing my browser.

Any help will be more than appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: my question is what do I miss in my code :)

Comment: Is there another way to submit required form inputs to a remote website ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting HTTP_USER_AGENT on your request?

Comment: Yes I do, request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.1)"; according to the fiddler